# A different version of an overloaded function(const int* const&/&&) gets called when passing const int* and int*

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion, rvalue, lvalue

I have came across a bug in my code where the wrong overloaded function was being called.

The problem boils down to this:

```
void func(const int* const& ptr){
    std::cout << "LValue reference\n";
}
void func(const int* const&& ptr){
    std::cout << "RValue reference\n";
}

int main(){
    const int* ptr;

    func(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above works as expected, it prints `LValue reference`.
However, when I change `const int* ptr` to `int* ptr`, the program prints `RValue reference`. This is bizarre to me, since I pass it a confirmed LValue.
This leads me to believe that some sort of an implicit conversion is happening which turns it into an RValue. I did look into it with the godbolt compiler explorer, which, at first glance, would confirm my suspicions, but I know nothing about assembly so I can't say for sure.

So the question is: What is happening here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `int*` is not the same type as a `const int*`.  Since they are not the same type a conversion must take place since you can't bind a reference to a different type then it is declared to refer to (except for when dealing with derived objects).

This means the `int*` is used to create a temporary `const int*` and this temporary pointer is an rvalue.  Since it is an rvalue the rvalue reference overload will be chosen.